# Is there a repository for pycharm_helpers

Tags: docker, pycharm, remote-debugging

Recently I have started using **PyCharm 2017** to use for ***remote debugging in Docker*** and I realized that with every version of PyCharm a new image of `pycharm_helpers` is pulled (with a different tag depending on the build).

Is there any way I can download all of the `pycharm_helpers` images? ...or do I need to download all the versions and run them in order to get the images... (believe it or not I don't want to do option B).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying and studying the build that happens to create the `pycharm_helpers` I realized it uses `busybox` as a base for the image.

Once I pulled the `busybox` image PyCharm was able to build the helper and my code was able to debug in the container no matter what version of PyCharm.

I hope this is helpful to others, especially since now you don't have to store the helpers in your registry.