# Can't add interpreter from Docker Image within Pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I have a project which contains a Dockerfile. It is normally used to build docker container on a server when it comes to deployment. Now I am trying to debug with docker locally.

I build the image for the dockfile inside Pycharm. And after the dockerfile run successfully, I see a docker contrainer and a few images as below:
[image]

Following this instruction, I was trying to add Python Interpreter from Docker.

> [Configure an interpreter using Docker](https://%20https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#config-docker)

[image]

However, in the dropdown menu, there are only three images to choose from. And my understanding is that the pycharm_helper image  should be the one I'm looking for.

- python:3
- ubuntu:18.04
- busybox:latest

I also read this post, and choose busybox:latest, but I don't know what should be the Python interpreter path for that either.

[Is there a repository for pycharm_helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043932/is-there-a-repository-for-pycharm-helpers)

Any one has idea on how to add Python Interpreter from the image I just built and run my code inside the container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm on its own needs a helper image to set up runtimes in your remote docker instance. If you've exposed your docker run time, pycharm already handles that for you, as seen by the following request

```
POST /v1.40/build?t=pycharm_helpers%3AIU-222.4345.14&rm=true HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/tar
encoding: gzip
Host: localhost:7777
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: okhttp/3.14.9
Content-Length: 20917196

[tarball]
```

Personally, I disagree with unpinned busybox version but that should be taken up with jetbrains as they've decided on what pycharm helpers should look like.

The following are issues with podman in particular:

There's a tendency to use non-fully qualified names for images, such as just `python:3.10.1` instead of `docker.io/library/python:3.10.1`, and podman insists on using prefix "localhost" when building an image rather than letting you tag images as is. As a result, pycharm will fail to find the "correct image" because its name isn't `pycharm_helpers` but rather `localhost/pycharm_helpers`. You can tag the image as `docker.io/library/[image name]` and pycharm will resolve the image.

Finally, pycharm will attempt to create containers with `seccomp:unconfined` which is invalid option in podman. If you're using a proxy, drop any mentions to that as well. I am unsure why it's being sent, nor what is it supposed to do.

Another podman specific issue I encountered was that docker plugin uses `--volumes-from` declaration to map over the helpers from pycharm helpers image. It seems that if you do not map over a physical location from host, podman will not map the helpers files into the target container (the one where your project would spawn from). As a result, you need to remake the pycharm helpers container by copying over the pycharm_helpers directory into the host, and then mapping that copied directory into the container at `/opt/.pycharm_helpers`.